# Custom jndi name for ejb3.X with Jboss 7.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I am migrating one application from weblogic to jboss7.1 and ejb2.0 to ejb3.X. The application is using jndi name for ejb lookup.

Could someone help me to find out how can i configure my custom jndi name with ejb3.0 and jboss 7.1.

I have read on internet that in Jboss 7.1 there is no concept of jndi-name. if it is true. could someone let me know how can i lookup this jndi name, getting registered by jboss for ejbs present in ejb-jar.xml

```
    java:global/pirptfe/RRMSessionFacadeEJB!com.bfm.app.pirptfe.heatmap.ejb.RRMSessionFacadeHome
java:app/pirptfe/RRMSessionFacadeEJB!com.bfm.app.pirptfe.heatmap.ejb.RRMSessionFacadeHome
java:module/RRMSessionFacadeEJB!com.bfm.app.pirptfe.heatmap.ejb.RRMSessionFacadeHome
java:jboss/exported/pirptfe/RRMSessionFacadeEJB!com.bfm.app.pirptfe.heatmap.ejb.RRMSessionFacadeHome
java:global/pirptfe/RRMSessionFacadeEJB!com.bfm.app.pirptfe.heatmap.ejb.RRMSessionFacadeRemote
java:app/pirptfe/RRMSessionFacadeEJB!com.bfm.app.pirptfe.heatmap.ejb.RRMSessionFacadeRemote
java:module/RRMSessionFacadeEJB!com.bfm.app.pirptfe.heatmap.ejb.RRMSessionFacadeRemote
java:jboss/exported/pirptfe/RRMSessionFacadeEJB!com.bfm.app.pirptfe.heatmap.ejb.RRMSessionFacadeRemote
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer of my question. in ejb3.X on jboss7.1 and above there is no concept of custom jndi. you have to call your ejb as below

ctx.lookup("java:global/pirptfe/RRMSessionFacadeEJB!com.bfm.app.pirptfe.heatmap.ejb.RRMSessionFacadeHome");